# how to change the position of view on orientation change with just storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard, uiinterfaceorientation, ios-autolayout

I have a view B which comes below view A on Potrait
but when the device changes its orientation to landscape then I want the view B to be horizontally paralell to view A

I am able to do this by adding removing constraints programatically but it seems to be a overkill.

Any solutions on how to do it storyboard itself.

Comment: Writing out constraints is overkill? Looking for a checkbox to tick on Interface Builder instead? Welcome to the new generation of GUI coding. When you tick those boxes on Interface Builder, you're adding code to your application, you just don't see it. And sometimes it adds a lot of code. IMO, there is nothing overkill about writing out a few constraints, especially when it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "Trait Variation" in interface builder to specify what the layout should look like when portrait or landscape. https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_Trait_Variations_to_Design_Adaptive_iOS_User_Interfaces

Comment: If you don't mind,can you brief me a bit ,, cuz even for othres also it'd be useful... like how to do in my secenario thanks

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is using UIStackView. Add A and B as children, and set the axis to vertical (for portrait) or horizontal (for landscape).

It is possible to do that in storyboard by adding a variation on the Axis property:

[image]

I personally would add this variation in code, because all clever storyboard solutions tend to break down and feel as cludges after a while when you need to do maintenance.

Comment: I have to support iOS so I can't use stack view

Comment: Can you bried me a bit on how to do in my scenario plz ?

Comment: UICollectionView might work as well. It has scroll direction horizontal or vertical, but you can't set it from just storyboard, and it might be an overkill over constraints.

If you use constraints with the [visual format syntax](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/VisualFormatLanguage.html), it might be just a few lines of code.

Comment: I am not using either uitableview or Uicollectionview , just views

Comment: If you could give me a sample with just uilabels on the screen in the place of view A & B.it'd be much more helpful for me